# Amazon Cognito Push Sync Using Google Log-In And Firebase Cloud Messaging: Failed To Subscribe To Dataset

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, google-signin, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use Amazon Cognito Sync to remotely store and retrieve information about my user, and for that information to be synced across all devices that that user is logged into.

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/synchronizing-data.html) which shows how to create Dataset objects and how to use its get(), put(), and synchronize() methods.

After getting that working, I tried following the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/push-sync.html) which shows how to register a device for push notifications and subsequently subscribe to a Dataset that you want to keep synced.  However, when I call

```
cognitoSyncManager.subscribeAll()
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.exceptions.SubscribeFailedException: Failed to subscribe to dataset
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.internal.storage.CognitoSyncStorage.subscribeToDataset(CognitoSyncStorage.java:360)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.DefaultDataset.subscribe(DefaultDataset.java:604)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager.subscribe(CognitoSyncManager.java:332)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager.subscribeAll(CognitoSyncManager.java:319)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Failed to subscribe to dataset USER_INFORMATION, endpointArns do not exist (Service: AmazonCognitoSync; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 7e681e01-a872-11e7-9e5f-01c7f0419773)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.AmazonCognitoSyncClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoSyncClient.java:864)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.AmazonCognitoSyncClient.subscribeToDataset(AmazonCognitoSyncClient.java:663)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.internal.storage.CognitoSyncStorage.subscribeToDataset(CognitoSyncStorage.java:357)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.DefaultDataset.subscribe(DefaultDataset.java:604) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager.subscribe(CognitoSyncManager.java:332) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager.subscribeAll(CognitoSyncManager.java:319)
```

In my Android app, I'm authenticating the user using Google Sign-In, which gives me the token that I need when creating my Cognito Credentials Provider, and I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for getting the token needed by Cognito Sync Manager.  Here's the snippet of my code which results in the exceptions:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override public void run()
    {
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getContext(), Utilities.getString(R.string.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id), Regions.US_EAST_1);

        Map<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<>();

        loginsMap.put("accounts.google.com", GoogleLoginManager.getInstance().getToken());

        credentialsProvider.setLogins(loginsMap);

        credentialsProvider.refresh();

        cognitoId = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();

        isLoggedIn = !cognitoId.equals("");

        if(isLoggedIn)
        {
            CognitoSyncManager cognitoSyncManager = new CognitoSyncManager(getContext(), Regions.US_EAST_1, credentialsProvider);

            try
            {
                cognitoSyncManager.registerDevice("GCM", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId());
            }
            catch(RegistrationFailedException exception)
            {
                Log.e(exception);
            }
            catch(AmazonClientException exception)
            {
                Log.e(exception);
            }

            if(cognitoSyncManager.isDeviceRegistered())
            {
                try
                {
                    cognitoSyncManager.subscribeAll();
                }
                catch(SubscribeFailedException exception)
                {
                    Log.e(exception);
                }
                catch(AmazonClientException exception)
                {
                    Log.e(exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Following the tutorials and navigating the developer console have been a bit of an enigma for me, and I feel like there must be some core concept that I'm just not getting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  When calling `cognitoSyncManager.registerDevice()` I was passing `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId()` as the token instead of `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.  Bleh.

Also, before calling `cognitoSyncManager.registerDevice("GCM", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId());` I now call `cognitoSyncManager.unregisterDevice()`.  Apparently, if you call `registerDevice()` in a previous run of the app and the registration wasn't actually successful, the CognitoSyncManager class still stores in SharedPreferences that it's registered, and thus will block all future calls to `registerDevice()` until `unregisterDevice()` is called.